# Two column select spinner in iOS

Tags: html, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

Is it possible for a select menu to open a spinner with two columns in iOS? Similar to how when you have an input type of date iOS opens its customised spinner with different columns that are all individually selectable.

Sorry should have specified "in HTML"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using native controls, no. There are a few libraries for this already available mind you:

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/sw/ is a good example of one that mimics the iOS interface.

Comment: ok thanks very much, this is probably the best route then, cheers

Comment: I think it's your best option using HTML and JS alone.